# Can I restore a Unix server by copypasting system directories from a backup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, backup

I messed up a Ubuntu server with lots of installed binaries, settings, etc. I'm going to have to reinstall Ubuntu, but I have a complete backup, hidden files and all, though not bootable. I'm hoping to avoid installing and configuring everything all over again.

If I copy all the system directories (bin, usr/bin, var, etc and so on) from the backup to a new installation, which presumably includes all my config files, will everything work right away as if i reinstalled the binaries through apt-get? Let's assume I'll exclude any directories that need excluding (eg boot and dev) too.

If that doesn't work, given I still have complete disk access, what would be the quickest, most painless way to restore everything? To be clear, since it's a server, I don't actually care about the /home directory, but rather everything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely work, you just need to preserve file permissions, this can be archieved with `cp -a`.

The only Issue I could think of is your backup system being outdated in some way which will make it unusable for your current kernel (e.g a different init system). Simply copying the system Is also what I do when I want to migrate my system to another hard drive/partition.

As you can't screw anything up because , you still have complete disk access afterwards , it is definitely worth a try.